# Novel series with a half-cyborg hero with two left arms

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel quite a few years ago (around 2007). It was a series of funny novels set in the future, and most probably another planet also. The hero was a half-cyborg, with a robotic left arm implanted in place of his right arm, i.e. he had two left arms.

Answer (score 26):

That would be [Bill the Galactic hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill,_the_Galactic_Hero), by Harry Harrison.  He had two left arms and, like his other humorous series, The Stainless Steel Rat, was quite entertaining.  While his foot was artificial, I believe his second left arm was from a human.  Still, he did have artificial parts that made him a cyborg.

Comment: Bill  lost his right arm and the only replacement was a left arm.  He could shake hands with himself.

Comment: I remember seeing two different printings of this book, with different cover art. One showed Bill with both left arms on the left side of his body, and no arm on the right. The other showed him with his natural left arm on the left side, and the transplanted left arm on his right side. But as I still haven't read the book (it's been on my must-read list for years), I still don't know which rendering is correct!

Comment: He also had a chicken foot if I recall correctly.